# Meaning of "col" vs "col_choice" in answers?

Tags: surveymonkey

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses says:

```
data[_].questions[_].answers[_].row (Optional)    Id of a row type answer    String
data[_].questions[_].answers[_].col (Optional)    Id of a col type answer    String
data[_].questions[_].answers[_].col_hoice (Optional)    Id of a col_choice answer    String
```

What is an example of a question that would produce a col_choice answer? Is it a menu choice?
In the old relational database format we had these following defined in ResponseTable.html. 
What do they correspond to now?

For Qtype 50

```
Matrix of Drop-Down Menus    
key1=QuestionOptions.OptionID of row choice    
key2=QuestionOptions.OptionID of menu choice    
key3=QuestionOptions.OptionID of menu heading
```

For qtype=30, 40, or 60

```
key1=QuestionOptions.OptionID of row choice    
key2=0    
key3=QuestionOptions.OptionID of column choice
```

There is a mention of "column choice" there but I think that means "col" in the API, not "column_choice"
Can you confirm?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it by downloading a survey with a type 50 question, using the API and comparing it to a previous RDB download.

```
Key1 = row
Key2 = col_choice
Key3 = col
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the 'col_choice' attribute does indeed refer to the dropdown menu selection in a matrix of dropdown menus.